# setinterval countdown is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have js countdown function

```
var sTime = new Date().getTime();
var countDown = 60;

function RefreshThePage() {
var cTime = new Date().getTime();
var diff = cTime - sTime;
var seconds = countDown - Math.floor(diff / 1000);
if (seconds === 0) {
    location.reload(true);
}
if (seconds >= 0) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds -= minutes * 60;
    $("#minutes").text(minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes);
    $("#seconds").text(seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
} else {
    $("#countdown").hide();

    clearInterval(counter);
}
}
```

and in html side ,  I call this

```
 RefreshThePage();
           var counter = setInterval(RefreshThePage, 1000);
```

the issue is ,  normally it should refresh the page in 60 seconds but this code refreshs the page in 30 seconds. I don't know where the problem is ..

Comment: however, the code can just count in minutes, right? (due to secs -= floor(seconds/60)*60 )

Comment: For me it works as should've been. Here is some fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/n3y0reL6/

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/aw4swg06/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue

I forgot this html meta tag in somewhere in ui side

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />`